# Is there an OAuth wrapper library for Scala?

Tags: scala, oauth, delicious-api

Is there an OAuth wrapper library for Scala?

I am looking forward to work with my del.icio.us (authenticated via Yahoo account, so I am going to need OAuth) bookmarks base from a Scala code. Is there a wrapper library out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/About) has an OAuth client implementation. ([OAuth package API docs](http://databinder.net/dispatch-doc/dispatch/oauth/package.html))

Comment: link seems to be broken